# How to pass ThreeJS renderer to MapLibre GL JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, maplibre-gl

I want to make MapLibre work with other ThreeJS elements, allowing me to add various other components to the MapLibre.

I want to be able to:

1. initialise my scene+ renderer + camera, etc.
2. Initialise MapLibre GL adding it to the threeJS scene
3. Initialise a tileset using Loader3DTiles and add that to the scene

Currently, it seems that MapLibre GL initialises its own scene (if I understand correctly) and then to add new objects to it I create a layer. All I seem to be able to do is set the map.container and it creates the scene for me.

However, my application involves adding MapLibre GL to an existing ThreeJS project; I can't really pull the whole thing apart to make MapLibre the base.

Does anyone have any suggestions?